# How to create dynamic arrays and process it using php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create a dynamic array and process the data inside the array.
Example:

a) If have **2** as digit input value, then it must create 2^2 = 4 arrays with 2 elements each. These elements are in form of binary (2 elements) => 00, 01, 10, 11

```
[pre]
Array1[] = {0, 0};
Array2[] = {0, 1};
Array3[] = {1, 0};
Array4[] = {1, 1};
[/pre]
```

b) If i **3** as digit input value, then it must create 2^3 = 8 arrays with 3 elements each. These elements are in form of binary (3 elements) => 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111

```
[pre]
Array1[] = {0, 0, 0};
Array2[] = {0, 0, 1};
Array3[] = {0, 1, 0};
Array4[] = {0, 1, 1};
Array5[] = {1, 0, 0};
Array6[] = {1, 0, 1};
Array7[] = {1, 1, 0};
Array8[] = {1, 1, 1};
[/pre]
```

Then i want to use this Array elements to calculate how many presence of "000" to "111" in a mysql table. The table has only 2 rows: id (auto_increment) and value (0/1). Example of searching for "101" in the table:

```
[pre]
id | value
----------
1  |   1
2  |   1   --
3  |   0    |  => (1)
4  |   1   --
5  |   0     | => (2)
6  |   1   -- 
7  |   0
8  |   0
9  |   1
10 |   1
.. |   ..
.. |   ..
5000 |  1  --
5001 |  0    |  => (n)
5002 |  1  --
5003 |  1
...  |  ...
[/pre]
```

A friend (Barmar) gave a solution in mysql to get how many "101" presence in the table (this is for :  **Array6[] = {1, 0, 1};**  as example) , by using this code :

```
[pre]
select count(*) match_count
from TheTable t1
join TheTable t2 on t1.id+1 = t2.id
join TheTable t3 on t1.id+2 = t3.id
where t1.value = 1 and t2.value = 0 and t3.value = 1
[/pre]
```

**My Questions :**
 
***1) How to make the 8 arrays that hold the elements {0,0,0} ... {1,1,1} for an input = 3?***
  
***2) How to make the "FOR" routine for these 8 arrays to search for the pattern inside mysql table ?*** I tried this below, but the result was wrong ....

```
[pre]
....
for ($i=1; $i<=8; $i++) {    // this is 2^3 = 8 arrays
  for ($k=0; $k<3; $k++) {
    $element$k = Array$i[$k];  // get each array elements (3 elements in each array)
  }
  $result = select count(*) match_count
        from TheTable t1
        join TheTable t2 on t1.id+1 = t2.id
        join TheTable t3 on t1.id+2 = t3.id
        where t1.value = $element$k and t2.value = $element$k and t3.value =  $element$k;  // these values must change for every array ....

       $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO theResult(binary,presence) VALUES("'.$element$k.'","'.$result.'") ");

} // end of for
[/pre]
```

I expect to see this at mysql table "theResult" :

```
[pre]
binary  | presence
--------------------
000     | 21
001     | 18
010     | 32
011     | 11
100     | 44
101     | 17
110     | 8
111     | 25
[/pre]
```

But it doesn't happen like that ... :(
Please help.
Thank you

Comment: You're mixing php with SQL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for your exotic **1st problem** is:

```
$N = 3;

for($i = 0; $i < pow(2,$N); $i++)
    ${"Array".$i} = str_split(str_pad(decbin($i), $N, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT));
```

Now `$Array1`, `$Array2`, `...`, `$Array8` consist of desired subarrays with binary values.

For example, value for `$Array5` is

`array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "0" [2]=> string(1) "1" }`

The code is universal for natural `N`s.

**P.S.:** It is much more better to use regular PHP array `$arr[$i]` instead of surrogate array `${"Array".$i}`.

Comment: Thank you zavg. Can you give me a clue how to get the array elements?
    `for ($i=0; $i< pow(2,$N), $i++) {` 
        `for ($k=0; $k<$N; $k++) { `
          `$getElement.$k = $Array.$i[$k];` 
        `}` 
        `$result = select count(*) match_count` 
           `from TheTable t1` 
           `join TheTable t2 on t1.id+1 = t2.id` 
           `join TheTable t3 on t1.id+2 = t3.id where t1.value = $getElement.$k and t2.value = $getElement.$k and t3.value = $getElement.$k; // wrong here ? $getElement.$k will hold the same value ?` 
          `......` 
    `}`

Comment: Hi zavg, i think i can use "Foreach" instead of "for" routine in mysql query .... thank you

Comment: Hi zavg, i tried at LAMP:

   `print("<table><tr><td colspan=6><B>Result</B></td></tr>");
   $N=3;
   for($i = 0; $i < pow(2,$N); $i++) {
    ${"myArray".$i} = str_split(str_pad(decbin($i), $N, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT));
    echo('<tr><td colspan=6><B>3digit myArray: '.${"myArray".$i}.'
</B></td></tr>');
    }
    print("</table>");`

And as result i got this :
    `3digit myArray: Array
     3digit myArray: Array
     3digit myArray: Array
     3digit myArray: Array
     3digit myArray: Array
     3digit myArray: Array
     3digit myArray: Array
     3digit myArray: Array`

What is wrong?

Comment: @user2758001 To access items it is muxh more conveniebt to use just regurar PHP array `$myArray[$i]` instead of your suroggate array `${"Array".$i}`

Comment: You can not just print arrays with `print`. You should iterate through its values in loop and print each item separately.

Comment: Hi zavg, i try this : `for ($i=0; $i<pow(2,$N); $i++) {
  for ($k=0; $k<$N; $k++) {
   print("<tr><td colspan=6>Value of myArray".$i." element ".$k."
are :". $myArray[$i][$k]."</td></tr>");
  }
 }`
and i just got empty result ....
`Value of myArray0 element 0 are :
Value of myArray0 element 1 are :`

Comment: Then i changed to : `print("<tr><td colspan=6>Value of myArray".$i." element ".$k."
are :". $myArray.$i[$k]."</td></tr>"); ` , the result are also empty...

Comment: Hi zavg, this is the code : `$N=3;
 for ($i=0; $i<pow(2,$N); $i++) {
   ${"myArray".$i} = str_split(str_pad(decbin($i), $N, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT), 1);

   $res = decbin($i);
   $res2 = str_pad($res, $N, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
   $res3 = str_split($res2, 1);

   print("<tr><td colspan=6>Element of array are :". $res ." => ".
 $res2 . " => ". $res3[0]. " => ". $res3[1] ." => ". $res3[2] ." <
/td></tr>");
 }

 for ($i=0; $i<pow(2,$N); $i++) {
  for ($k=0; $k<$N; $k++) {
   print("<tr><td colspan=6>Value of myArray".$i." element ".$k."
is :". $myArray.$i[$k]."</td></tr>");
  }
`

Comment: and the result are :
`
Element of array are :0 => 000 => 0 => 0 => 0
Element of array are :1 => 001 => 0 => 0 => 1
Element of array are :10 => 010 => 0 => 1 => 0
Element of array are :11 => 011 => 0 => 1 => 1
Element of array are :100 => 100 => 1 => 0 => 0
Element of array are :101 => 101 => 1 => 0 => 1
Element of array are :110 => 110 => 1 => 1 => 0
Element of array are :111 => 111 => 1 => 1 => 1 
Value of myArray0 element 0 is :
Value of myArray0 element 1 is :
Value of myArray0 element 2 is :
Value of myArray1 element 0 is :
Value of myArray1 element 1 is :
Value of myArray1 element 2 is :`

Comment: And if i use "print_r" to call the array, like this :
`for ($i=0; $i<pow(2,$N); $i++) {
  for ($k=0; $k<$N; $k++) {
   print_r("<tr><td colspan=6>Value of myArray".$i." element ".$k.
" is :". $myArray.$i ."</td></tr>");
  }
 }`
I got this : 
`Value of myArray0 element 0 is :0
Value of myArray0 element 1 is :0
Value of myArray0 element 2 is :0
Value of myArray1 element 0 is :1
Value of myArray1 element 1 is :1
Value of myArray1 element 2 is :1`

Comment: So, result of : decbin, str_pad, str_split are no problem. I don't know why i still can not get the value hold by  ${"myArray".$i} ....

Comment: `$N=3; for ($i=0; $i<pow(2,$N); $i++) { $myArray[$i] = str_split(str_pad(decbin($i), $N, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT), 1); $res = decbin($i); $res2 = str_pad($res, $N, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); $res3 = str_split($res2, 1); print("<tr><td colspan=6>Element of array are :". $res ." => ". $res2 . " => ". $res3[0]. " => ". $res3[1] ." => ". $res3[2] ." < /td></tr>"); } for ($i=0; $i<pow(2,$N); $i++) { for ($k=0; $k<$N; $k++) { print("<tr><td colspan=6>Value of myArray".$i." element ".$k." is :". $myArray[$i][$k]."</td></tr>"); }`